AWS cdk deploy deletes the resources which is already created
am trying to create a stack which contains API Gateway and few lambdas based on a config.json file
When I Give CDK Deploy for the first time the stack and the resources are created successfully, but if I change the lambda code and give the cdk deploy it deletes the existing resources created with in the stack
below are the code what I have tried
infra-config.json
{
    "stackname":"hellostack",
    "apigateway":"hello_apigateway",
    "lambda":[
        {
            "lambdaName": "getresource",
            "lambdaPath": "../../lambda/get_resources",
            "endpoint": "getresources",
            "handler":"handler",
            "memorySize": 128,
            "method": "GET",
            "module":"ResourceManagement"
        },
        {
            "lambdaName": "updateclientmanaged",
            "lambdaPath": "../../lambda/update_client_managed",
            "endpoint": "updateclimngd",
            "handler":"handler",
            "memorySize": 256,
            "method": "PATCH",
            "module":"DealReview"
        }
    ] }

bin/infra.ts
    const account = '123456789';
const region = 'us-east-2';
const config: Config = getInfraConfig()

const app = new cdk.App();
const stackName = config.stackname;


// Main function to run cleanup and then deploy the stack
async function main() {
    try {
        const stack = new LambdaApiStack(app, stackName, {
            lambdaConfig: config,
            env: { account, region },

        });
        console.log(`Bundling process completed successfully for stack: ${stackName}`);
    } catch (error: any) {
        console.error(`Error during bundling process for stack: ${stackName}`, error);
        process.exit(1); // Terminate the process with an error code
    }
}

main();

lib/infra-stack.ts
interface LambdaApiStackProps extends cdk.StackProps {
  lambdaConfig: Config;
}
export class LambdaApiStack extends cdk.Stack {
  private apiEnv: string = 'dev'
  private apiEnvRegion: string = 'us-east-2'
  private apiSecretVersion: string = 'TESTVERSION'

  private readonly environmentVariables: any = {
    WHUB_AWS_REGION: this.apiEnvRegion,
    WHUB_ENV_INSTANCE: this.apiEnv,
    WHUB_AWS_SECRET_VERSION: this.apiSecretVersion
  };
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: LambdaApiStackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);
    const config: Config = props?.lambdaConfig;
    console.log(`config ${JSON.stringify(config)}`)
    const apiGatewayClient = new APIGatewayClient({});
    this.checkAndCreateApiGateway(apiGatewayClient, props?.lambdaConfig);
  }


  async checkAndCreateApiGateway(apiGatewayClient: APIGatewayClient, config: Config) {
    // Check if the API Gateway exists
    const apis = await apiGatewayClient.send(new GetRestApisCommand({}));
    const existingApi = apis.items?.find((api: any) => api.name === config.apigateway);

    let api;
    if (existingApi) {
      console.log(`existingApi ${JSON.stringify(existingApi)}`)

      api = apigateway.RestApi.fromRestApiAttributes(this, config.apigateway, {
        restApiId: existingApi.id!,
        rootResourceId: existingApi.rootResourceId!
      });
    } else {
      console.log(`inside Create the API Gateway`)

      // Create the API Gateway
      api = new apigateway.RestApi(this, config.apigateway, {
        restApiName: config.apigateway,
        deploy: false
      });
      console.log(`New APIGateway ${api.restApiId}`)

      const existingStage = api.deploymentStage;

      if (!existingStage || existingStage.stageName.toLowerCase() !== 'prod') {
        console.log(`existingStage ${existingStage}`)

        const deployment = new apigateway.Deployment(this, `${config.apigateway}-${this.apiEnv}-deploy`, {
          api,
        });

        new apigateway.Stage(this, `${config.apigateway}-${this.apiEnv}`, {
          deployment
        });
      }
      const cfnApi = api.node.defaultChild as apigateway.CfnRestApi;
      cfnApi.applyRemovalPolicy(cdk.RemovalPolicy.RETAIN);
    }

    for (const lambdaConfig of config.lambda) {
      await this.processLambdaConfig(api, lambdaConfig);
    }
  }

  async processLambdaConfig(api: apigateway.IRestApi, lambdaConfig: LambdaConfig) {
    console.log(`inside processLambdaConfig`)
    const lambdaAssetPath = path.join(__dirname, lambdaConfig.lambdaPath + '\\index.ts');
    const packageLockPath = path.join(__dirname, '../../', '\\package-lock.json');
    const lambdaClient = new LambdaClient({ region: this.apiEnvRegion });

    const lambdaName = `${this.apiEnv}_${lambdaConfig.lambdaName}`;
    console.log(`packageLockPath ${packageLockPath}`)

    console.log(`lambdaAssetPath ${lambdaAssetPath}`)
    if (!fs.existsSync(lambdaAssetPath)) {
      throw new Error(`Lambda asset path does not exist: ${lambdaAssetPath}`);
    }

    let lambdaRole = this.node.tryFindChild('dev-testexecrole-wa-hubb') as iam.IRole;
    if (!lambdaRole) {
      lambdaRole = iam.Role.fromRoleArn(this, `dev-testexecrole-wa-hubb`, `arn:aws:iam::1234567889:role/dev-testexecrole-wa-hubb`);

    }
    console.log(`Before lambdaExist`)
    try {
      await lambdaClient.send(new GetFunctionCommand({ FunctionName: lambdaName }));
      await lambdaClient.send(new UpdateFunctionConfigurationCommand({
        FunctionName: lambdaName,
        MemorySize: lambdaConfig.memorySize,
        Handler: lambdaConfig.handler,
        Environment: {
          Variables: this.environmentVariables
        }
      }));

      await lambdaClient.send(new UpdateFunctionCodeCommand({
        FunctionName: lambdaName,
        ZipFile: fs.readFileSync(lambdaAssetPath)
      }));

    }
    catch (err: any) {
      if (err.name === 'ResourceNotFoundException') {
        console.log(`After lambdaExist`)

        const lambdaFunction = new NodejsFunction(this, `${this.apiEnv}_${lambdaConfig.lambdaName}`, {
          functionName: `${this.apiEnv}_${lambdaConfig.lambdaName}`,
          memorySize: lambdaConfig.memorySize,
          timeout: cdk.Duration.minutes(2),
          runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_20_X,
          handler: lambdaConfig.handler,
          role: lambdaRole,
          entry: lambdaAssetPath,
          bundling: {
            externalModules: ['aws-lambda'],
            nodeModules: ['pg']
          },
          depsLockFilePath: packageLockPath,
          environment: this.environmentVariables
        });


        const integration = new apigateway.LambdaIntegration(lambdaFunction, {
          requestTemplates: { 'application/json': '{ "statusCode": "200" }' },
        });
        let rootResource = api.root.getResource(this.apiEnv);
        if (!rootResource) {
          rootResource = api.root.addResource(this.apiEnv);
          console.log("Root Res Created", rootResource)
        }
        let moduleResource = rootResource.getResource(`${lambdaConfig.module}`);
        if (!moduleResource) {
          moduleResource = rootResource.addResource(`${lambdaConfig.module}`);
          console.log("Module Res Created", moduleResource)
        }
        let resource = moduleResource.getResource(lambdaConfig.endpoint);
        if (!resource) {
          resource = moduleResource.addResource(lambdaConfig.endpoint);
          resource.addMethod(lambdaConfig.method, integration);
          console.log("Resource Created", resource)
        }
        else {
          resource.addMethod(lambdaConfig.method, integration);
          console.log("Resource Already Exist")
        }

        lambdaFunction.grantInvoke(new iam.ServicePrincipal('apigateway.amazonaws.com'));
        const cfnLambdaFunction = lambdaFunction.node.defaultChild as CfnResource;
        cfnLambdaFunction.applyRemovalPolicy(cdk.RemovalPolicy.RETAIN);

      }
    }
  }
}


Which resources does it delete? What is the output of cdk diff after you introduce a change to the lambda code?

@gshpychka all the resources are get deleted only the cdktoolkit metadata is only available in the stack, cdk diff shows all resources delete template

Okay, I see what you're doing. You should not make any API calls in your CDK code - it should be deterministic. Your code is telling CDK to not put any resources in the template if they exist. When you then try to deploy this template (with no resources), it replaces the already deployed stack, destroying all resources.
CloudFormation will perform these checks for you - you simply define what should be deployed in the end, with no imperative checks.

@gshpychka am not making any API call's from CDK just reading the Json config like stack name api-gateway-name from it, also have tried without any checks it throws error stating that resource already exist am not sure what's wrong in my code, if you have time, please have a look and point me the lines where am doing wrong, Thanks!

You are - apiGatewayClient.send makes an API call. Your code should not perform any checks of the existing environment - it should only specify what the result should be.

@gshpychka do you think that will be the reason

Yes. The CDK code defines the final state, not what should be added/removed.
